# How to execute queries on Hive tables sent over Kafka in Spark Streaming app?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have a Spark Streaming application that reads Hive table names in records from Kafka, e.g. table1.. table2.. table3.. etc.

I'd like to execute a structured query on the hive tables and stream the results to another Kafka topic.

I have it like this

```
val hqls = rdd
    .filter(record => record.value() != null && record.value().trim.length > 0)
    .foreach(tableName=> publishData(tableName, sparkSession, kafkaProducer))
```

My `publishData` is as below

```
val df = sparkSession.sql("select * from " + tableName)
df.foreach { row =>
  // code to write to kafka
}
```

When I execute this I get a `NullPointerException` at `sparkSession.sql` call as below:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 13 in stage 12.0 failed 8 times, most recent failure: Lost task 13.7 in stage 12.0 (TID 838, cilhdwks0001.sys.cigna.com, executor 1): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:142)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:140)
```

I found in other posts that it is not possible to run `val df = sparkSession.sql(hql)` inside `rdd.foreach`, but have not found how to do it properly.

If I change the code to use `collect` as follows it does works. Why?

```
val tablenames = rdd
  .filter(tableName => tableName != null && tableName.trim.length > 0)
  .collect() 
tablenames.foreach { tablename => 
  publishData(tablename, sparkSession, kafkaProducer)
}
```

Is it efficient and will it distribute the load properly to the cluster?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a set of hive table names that come via kafka to my Spark Streaming app. I need to execute a query against each of the tables

Once you start streaming your Hive tables to Kafka, all Spark sees (regardless whether you do Spark SQL or Spark Streaming or Spark Structured Streaming) are records that all together (in a single batch) may or may not correspond to the Hive tables. A single processing cycle could see just a half of a table or one and a half. It's not predictable.

IMHO You'd have to send a marker record so Spark could filter out all the records that belong to a single Hive table to a Dataset. That could work but I doubt is the most desirable solution.

In short, in Spark you work with a single Kafka record (that comes from a Hive table) and unless you send some extra metadata Spark won't know whether an entire Hive table is in a Dataset.

> `.foreach(tableName=> publishData`

Whatever you do in `publishData` happens on Spark executors where the `SparkContext` and `SparkSession` are not available. You simply cannot use them on executors (per Spark design) and hence *"a NullPointerException at sparkSession.sql"* That's expected.

> If I change it to (...) `.collect()` (...) it works
>   is it efficient and will it distribute the load properly to the cluster?

Any `collect` in a Spark application breaks the premise of Spark to distribute a large dataset across nodes in a cluster so you can process more than a single machine can handle. Any `collect` brings all the distributed data to a single JVM of the driver and may lead to OutOfMemoryErrors (which may have been the reasons why you considered Apache Spark for processing large datasets in the first place).